# Set range for specific column in Pivot Table issue

Tags: excel, vba, range, pivot-table

[image]

I've created a pivot table in VBA and would like to copy just certain columns to a new table.
The first section of the code works fine when I copy all the row columns, but my syntax is incorrect when I try to copy only specific data columns. I've added an image for an easier explanation.

My pivot table layout is as follows:

**Rows**: contains 8 columns

**Values**: 1 column ("Count of Site")

**Columns**: 1 ("MS"). Which has 7 values, but could be more in the future. I'm only interested in the one that shows "4". and then the grand total.

I only want to copy the DatabodyRange of the column "4" and the DatabodyRange of "Count of Site" (which is the grand total column)

So 2nd and 3rd part doesn't work (marked in the code).

The 2nd part only copies the 7 headings under "MS" and pastes them into the whole table range I set. It should only copy data from under 1 heading ("4").

The 3rd part copies all the data in the value columns. So all the data under the headings mentioned above a swell, not just the "Grand total" databodyrange.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").RowRange
    Set CopyRange = rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 2, rng.Columns.Count)

'THIS PART WORKS
    With CopyRange
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With

'2ND PART THAT DOESN'T WORK    
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").PivotFields("MS").DataRange
    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Number of Stores Ranged").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With

'3RD PART THAT DOESN'T WORK    
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").PivotFields("Count of Site").DataRange
    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Total Number of Stores : In Province").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
```

I've been on this for hours, but can't find a solution online. I've tried various methods, but don't know enough about Pivottables and how they work in VBA code.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I got the 2nd part to work, with help from the comments. I had to add the PivotItem, and change the range size it was adding to.

The 3rd part is still not working. It's still copying the whole Value datarange when I use "Count of Sites". It errors when I try to use `PivotItem("Grand total")` or `PivotItem("Row Grand Total")`

Updated code is as follows:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").RowRange
    Set CopyRange = rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 2, rng.Columns.Count)

'1ST PART WORKS
    With CopyRange
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With

'2ND PART WORKS
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").PivotFields("MS").PivotItems("4").DataRange
    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Number of Stores Ranged").DataBodyRange.Value = .Value
    End With

'3RD PART NOT WORKING
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").PivotFields("Count of Site").DataRange
    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Total Number of Stores : In Province").DataBodyRange.Value = .Value
    End With
```

I presume the problem is how to reference the "Grand Total" column? But I can't figure out what VBA code is seeing the column header as since it doesn't accept the methods mentioned above.

Comment: There's no image attached?  This is a good reference for pivot table ranges: https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: 2nd Part `rng.Copy wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Number of Stores Ranged").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)`  ..... .. .3rd Part  `rng.Copy wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Total Number of Stores : In Province").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: `'CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count` The size of this part doesn't seem to match with rng.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry not sure why the image didn't attach. I'll try again. Thank you for the link, it was helpful. I did look at similar posts last night but nothing seemed to work. I might have been overtired. I've managed to fix the 2nd Part now, but the 3rd part is still not working. I'll update the post.

Comment: @NareshBhople thanks for the reply. My size part was wrong in the 2nd and 3rd part, which I've fixed now. I want to avoid 'copy'. Therefore I used `.value`. Fixed version is in my edit.

Comment: @Dy.Lee It does work in the first section. My issues were in the 2nd and 3rd section, the resizing was wrong in them for the table it was adding values to. I've added the fix in my edit in the post. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Do you want to copy Grand Totals for the columns as well?

Comment: @NareshBhople Yes I want to copy the databodyrange (all data except the heading) under "Grand Total" column

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting my own answer since it's different from the suggested answers. 
Even though both the above will work (and most likely be the best solution for most people with the same issue), I got a shorter version that works for my situation just fine.

I do find it very odd that you cannot directly reference the Grand total field like you can other Pivot table fields or items...

But my solution was simply to remove the "MS" field from the column (or I just moved it to the Pagefield) and then use databodyrange to get the "Grand total" column's values.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").RowRange
    Set CopyRange = rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 2, rng.Columns.Count)

'1ST CODE PART
    With CopyRange
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With

'2ND CODE PART    
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").PivotFields("MS").PivotItems("4").DataRange
    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Number of Stores Ranged").DataBodyRange.Value = .Value
    End With

'3RD CODE PART    
    With wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata")
        With .PivotFields("MS")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End With


    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").DataBodyRange
    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged").ListColumns("Total Number of Stores : In Province").DataBodyRange.Value = .Value
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the code below to suit your range references names .

```
Sub GetRowItems()

Dim pf As Range
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

For i = 1 To pt.TableRange1.Columns.Count
    Set pf = pt.TableRange1.Columns(i)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2"). _
        ListColumns("Column" & i).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1). _
        Resize(pf.Rows.Count - 1, pf.Columns.Count).Value = _
        pf.Offset(2, 0).Resize(pf.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value

Next
End Sub
```

If you want to copy specific named pivot column (as per your comment below) say "Ramesh" in this case.

```
Sub GetRowItems()

Dim pf As Range
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

'for "Ramesh" Column number wiil be
x = pt.TableRange1.Rows(2).Find("Ramesh").Column - pt.TableRange1.Column + 1
Debug.Print x
    Set pf = pt.TableRange1.Columns(x)

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2"). _
        ListColumns("Column" & x).DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1). _
        Resize(pf.Rows.Count - 1, pf.Columns.Count).Value = _
        pf.Offset(2, 0).Resize(pf.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value

End Sub
```

[image]

So, your code will look something like (Please check)

```
'2ND PART WORKS
    x = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").TableRange1.Rows(2).Find("4").Column _
        - wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").TableRange1.Column + 1
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").TableRange1.Columns(x)
    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged"). _
        ListColumns("Number of Stores Ranged").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1). _
        Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count).Value = _
        rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value
    End With

'3RD PART NOT WORKING
    x = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").TableRange1.Rows(2).Find("Grand Total").Column _
        - wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").TableRange1.Column + 1
    Set rng = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata").TableRange1.Columns(x)

    With rng
        wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged").ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged"). _
        ListColumns("Total Number of Stores : In Province").DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1). _
        Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count).Value = _
        rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Value
    End With
```

Comment: I believe your code will copy all the data that's in the pivot table doing it this way? I only want to copy 2 different columns. 1st one (which is the 2nd part of the code) is "4" and 2nd column (3rd part of the code) is "grand total". The table data is dynamic, so the amount of data value columns will differ every week. But I always just need to copy those 2....

Comment: Yes, you can then add a line to define column number in pf .. In above example, "Ramesh" Column number will be `x = pt.TableRange1.Find("Ramesh").Column - pt.TableRange1.Column + 1` which is eqalu to 4

Comment: Thanks for the help Naresh, but I found a quicker method. I just removed the "MS" field so that I'm left with the totals only, then copied the databodyrange of the PivotTable. My method might not be the best for everyone, but it does work for my needs. I'll update the my post soon. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Grand Totals then this should work:

```
Set lo = wb.Worksheets("Number of Stores Ranged") _
           .ListObjects("Table_Number_of_Stores_Ranged")
Set pt = wsPivot.PivotTables("PvtSDCdata")

With pt.DataBodyRange
    Set rng = .Columns(.Columns.Count) 'last column = Grand totals
End With
lo.ListColumns("Total Number of Stores : In Province").DataBodyRange.Value = rng.Value
```

Might be worth adding a line to ensure the totals are actually being displayed.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this would've worked. I do have a line earlier in the code to make sure they are displayed as well. I've added my solution below. Works in my case, but yours might be better in the future.